# In Wordpress, is it possible, to add actions to hook conditionally for a click on a button, in frontend?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am making a product bundler (a gift box with any products) in woocommerce, but I have  two buttons on frontend:
button1: I want to collect some products for my gift box
button2: I want to see predefined gift boxes.

I made the first option with this:
`add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'getList', 10,0);` - where the getList function has some input field with special products, so I can send the selected products to the cart, it works fine.

But... If a customer chooses to see the predefined boxes, I do not need to add the getList function, but some other function to choose from a list, etc, that is a different question.

I'm wondering to use some session storage variables to send the data, which button clicked? However, it rerenders the page for all clicks.

Another idea - sound a nightmare - to stuff everything to one function, then with jQuery, set "display: none/block" one-half of the echoed HTML elements of the function.

Sorry if it is a stupid question, I came from the world of react.js, and the whole WordPress is quite a different world.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually display buttons and also run conditional operations with a single hook. Please take a look at this code below:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'display_bundles');

function display_bundles(){
    
   if (isset($_POST['bundleBtn']) && $_POST['bundleBtn'] == 'get_products_list' ) {
       
       // write code to display your product list. sample given below:
       echo "<h3>Create your own bundle:</h3>";
       echo "<ul>";
       echo "<li>Product 1</li>";
       echo "<li>Product 2</li>";
       echo "<li>Product 3</li>";
       echo "</ul>";
       
   }
   if (isset($_POST['bundleBtn']) && $_POST['bundleBtn'] == 'get_predefined_bundles' ) {

       // write code to display your predefined bundles. sample given below:
        echo "<h3>Select from Predefined Bundles:</h3>";
        echo "<ul>";
        echo "<li>Predefined Bundle 1</li>";
        echo "<li>Predefined Bundle 2</li>";
        echo "<li>Predefined Bundle 3</li>";
        echo "</ul>";
       
   }
   
    ?>
    <form id="btnform1" method="post" action="">
        <input type="hidden" name="bundleBtn" value="get_products_list" />
        <input type="submit" name="btn_get_list_submit" value="Create Bundle from Products" />
    </form>
    <form id="btnform2" method="post" action="">
        <input type="hidden" name="bundleBtn" value="get_predefined_bundles" />
        <input type="submit" name="btn_get_list_submit" value="View Predefined Bundles" />
    </form>
    <?php
}
```

My approach to the problem using the above code is this:

1. Write a single custom function that hooks to `woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button` to display buttons and also do some operations
2. The custom function outputs two buttons wrapped in two html forms. One button is to get products lists and the second button is to get predefined bundles.
3. Each button sends a unique POST value with the name `bundleBtn` whenever they are clicked. We use that POST value to find what user wants.
4. Based on the user's choice, we then display either products list or predefined bundles.

And finally, you need to write codes within those IF conditions to make this work.